# Get SharePoint 2013 Reports data

Tags: report, sharepoint-2013, analytics, return-type

I am building a custom analytics project for SharePoint 2013, with my own database and everything. The key is that I need to get data about queries, site collection, clicks,... and the way I am making this is by copying from SharePoint's database to mine.

There are some default libraries to do this, and I'm using this code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {
                // You can use SPContext.Current.Site.ID if you have HttpContext
                try
                {
                    using (var site = new SPSite(url))
                    {
                        var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                        var searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
                        var topQueries = searchProxy.GetSearchReport(1, Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30), false, 10);

                        foreach (QueryReportData query in topQueries)
                        {
                            //And here is where I work with the results
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
```

Everything in this code is fine, but what I need to know is the meaning of the first argument at `GetSearchReport()`. I know that writing '1' the method returns the "Top Queries" report, and I would like to know what else can return modifying this argument.

Answer (score 0):

`GetSearchReport` has the following parameters and meaning of each parameter is explained below.

- > **reportType** – int : type of report, e.g. 1 is for top search terms (top queries)
- > **tenantId** – guid : id of the SharePoint tenant.
- > **siteId** – guid : Site Collection id. Empty guid for all site collections.
- > **reportDate** – DateTime : The date of the report.
- > **bDaily** – bool : true value brings the result for that day, false value returns for the entire month.
- > **maxRows** – uint : maximum number of results.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found on the net. The thing is that at "reportType" you can see:

"reportType – int : type of report, e.g. 1 is for top search terms (top queries)"

But what about the other numbers? 2, 3, 4...? What type of reports are they?